# Как создать Json файл c# и заполнить его так что бы он виглядел:

Tags: c#, json

Как создать Json файл и заполнить его так что бы он виглядел:

```
{
    "media": [
        {
            "type": "text",
            "text": "This is a text of a new topic"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: гуглите `сериализация/десиреализация json в c#`. Для этих целей обычно используют библиотеку `Newtonsoft`. Но есть и встроенные объекты `Json`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Результат будет сохранен тут D:\myJson.json

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            var obj = new JsonObject
            {
                Media = new Media[]
                {
                    new Media
                    {
                        Type = "text",
                        Text = "This is a text of a new topic"
                    } 
                }
            };

            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Formatting.Indented);
            File.WriteAllText(@"D:\myJson.json", json);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class JsonObject
    {
        [JsonProperty("media")]
        public Media[] Media { get; set; }
    }

    public class Media
    {
        [JsonProperty("type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("text")]
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }
}
```